# Change "date" Command To 12 Hour Time Instead Of 24

Tags: command-line, date

When I type `date` in gnome-terminal, or xterm it reads out in 24 hour time, is there any way to make it use 12 hour. According to `date --help` using `%r` should do the trick, but there are no examples given as to how to input that command. I've tried `date %r`, and `date%r` but they don't work. It should be noted that my GUI clock on the top panel of my screen is using 12 hour format at the moment.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a "+" before the option like This,

```
date +%r
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/date.1.html),

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]
> ```

you have to put the format after a `+` sign.

```
date +%r
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an alias for date in .bashrc by typing `alias date=date +%r` and then doing `source .bashrc`, if you want to change date default format.